# Jekyll: code is getting highligheted unwantingly

Tags: jekyll

I've got the following page:

```
---
layout: default
status: publish
published: true
title: Categories
author:
  display_name: lucas
---
{% for category in site.categories %}
  <li><a name="{{ category | first }}">{{ category | first }}</a>
    <ul>
    {% for posts in category %}
      {% for post in posts %}
        <li><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
      {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Instead of listing the hrefs per categery, it somehow gets code highlighting: 
[image]

Can anyone help me out preventing the code getting highlighted? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @David Jacquel, `.md` files are automatically parsed as markdown, in which four space indentations are treated as preformatted code.

I followed his suggestion on my website: change all files to `.html`. This disabled Markdown parsing in the file. However, if you are unwilling to write in pure HTML and would still like to use Markdown, there is a workaround.

- For each element that you would like Markdown to ignore, give it the attribute `markdown="0"`.
- For each element that you would like Markdown to parse, give it the attribute `markdown="1"`.

In your case, the following is a possible implementation.

```
...
<div markdown="0">
{% for category in site.categories %}
  <li><a name="{{ category | first }}">{{ category | first }}</a>
    <ul>
    {% for posts in category %}
      {% for post in posts %}
        <li><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
      {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it a `.md` file ? If yes, try to change for an `.html` extension.
In markdown four space indentation is used to print code tag.